# Pyspark combine different rows base on a column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe

```
+----------------+------------+-----+
|           Sport|Total_medals|count|
+----------------+------------+-----+
|   Alpine Skiing|           3|    4|
|   Alpine Skiing|           2|   18|
|   Alpine Skiing|           4|    1|
|   Alpine Skiing|           1|   38|
|         Archery|           2|   12|
|         Archery|           1|   72|
|       Athletics|           2|   50|
|       Athletics|           1|  629|
|       Athletics|           3|    8|
|       Badminton|           2|    5|
|       Badminton|           1|   86|
|        Baseball|           1|  216|
|      Basketball|           1|  287|
|Beach Volleyball|           1|   48|
|        Biathlon|           4|    1|
|        Biathlon|           3|    9|
|        Biathlon|           1|   61|
|        Biathlon|           2|   23|
|       Bobsleigh|           2|    6|
|       Bobsleigh|           1|   60|
+----------------+------------+-----+
```

Is there a way for me to combine the value of counts from multiple rows if they are from the same sport?

For example, if Sport = Alpine Skiing I would have something like this:

```
+----------------+-----+
|           Sport|count|
+----------------+-----+
|   Alpine Skiing|   61|
+----------------+-----+
```

where count is equal to 4+18+1+38 = 61. I would like to do this for all sports

any help would be appreciated

Comment: `import pyspark.sql.functions as f; df.groupby('Sport').agg(f.sum('count'))` ?

Comment: I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `groupby` on the Sport column and then `aggregate` the count column with the `sum()` function.

Example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
grouped_df = df.groupby('Sport').agg(F.sum('count'))
```